# How to post a list to controller in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf,Maybe this is a simple question.Please help me.Thanks.

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

@GetMapping(value = "/")
public String testget(Map<String, Object> model) {
    TestBean bean = new TestBean();
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int index = 1; index < 5; index++) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setId(index);
        p.setName("name" + index);
        list.add(p);
    }
    model.put("allList", "nothing");
    bean.setList(list);
    model.put("testbean", bean);
    return "NewFile";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/")
public String testpost(Map<String, Object> model//
        , @ModelAttribute(name = "testbean") TestBean bean) {
    List<Person> list = bean.getList();
    model.put("bean", bean);
    model.put("allList", list.toString());
    return "NewFile";
}}
```

simple mapper and a Person bean:

```
@Data
public class TestBean {

   private List<Person> list;

}

@Data
public class Person {
   private int id;
   private String name;
}
```

HTML code :

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${testbean}" method="post">
    <p th:text="'ALL : ' + ${allList}"></p>
    <table>
        <tr th:each="person : ${testbean.list}">
            <td>Id:<input type="text" th:value="${person.id}" 
             /></td>
            <td>name: <input type="text" th:value="${person.name}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I want put list to page and change properties to refresh.
but i don't know how to add **th:field** tag, I try to add

```
**th:field="*{testbean.list[__${index}__].id}"**
```

but it failed with :

```
Invalid property 'testbean' of bean class [com.TestBean]
```

> UPDATE1

And i tried

```
th:field="*{list[__${index}__].id}"
```

I got a error Where I added **th:field**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (NewFile:14)] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
```

My questions is what i can do something that i can get a **List** in controller.

Comment: try `th:field="*{list[__${index}__].id}` without `testbean` if you use `*` notation then it will reference to parent object.

Comment: Thank your help.I also tried.The other [error For input string: "null"] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (NewFile:14)] with root cause

Comment: add any varible "rowStat" to loop keep status index `th:each="person,rowStat : ${testbean.list}"` and access it like `th:field="*{list[__${rowStat.index}__].id}`

Comment: Amazing, Now it's work fine, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Invalid property 'testbean' of bean class [com.TestBean]

Use `th:field="*{list[__${index}__].id}` pattern without `testbean` definition. If you use `*` notation then it will reference to parent object.

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"

Add any variable like "rowStat" to the loop for keeping status index:

```
th:each="person,rowStat : ${testbean.list}"
```

and access it like `th:field="*{list[__${rowStat.index}__].id}`. So index will not be null and no problem converting the string to int.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it on page that lists some search results - table with checkboxes. Code itself is stripped only to relevant lines. `places.content` is a collection of `Place` objects.

```
 <form th:action="@{selected-places}" method="POST" >
 <tr th:each="place,i : ${places.content}">
     <td><input name="places" th:value="${place.id}" type="checkbox"></td>
 </tr>
 </form>
```

And the controller side

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/selected-places", params = "action=delete")
    public String deletePlaces(@RequestParam Place[] places, RedirectAttributesModelMap model) { 
      ....
     }
```

As you can see, despite fact that form is sending only list of IDs, spring will autohydrate model entities. You can always `Place[] places` to collection of integers and it still will work.