# How to bind values to thymeleaf object from html table row and send to spring MVC controller's modelAttribute

Tags: spring-mvc, html-table, thymeleaf, request-mapping

I am new to Thymeleaf and tried all possible solutions and workaround from web. Desperately I need some help to figure out on what is wrong here.

Not able get cart object(thymeleaf) value updated from html to MVC controller. instead CartViewModel object's fields (userI and products) in cart and modelMap objects are coming as null. even it is not getting values which i passed to populate the table in previous call.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks for your valuable time in advance.

[Controller debug status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzrki.png)

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    IProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    IVendorService vendorService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String getVendors(VendorViewModel vendorViewModel, final ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("vendors", vendorService.getVendors());

        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/inventory", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public String getProductsForSelectedVendor(VendorViewModel vendorViewModel, final ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("vendors", vendorService.getVendors());
        modelMap.addAttribute("cart", new CartViewModel("Nish", productService.getProductsByVendor(vendorViewModel.getId())));

        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cart", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public String saveCart(@ModelAttribute(name = "cart") CartViewModel cart, ModelMap modelMap, BindingResult bindingResult) {

**//not able get cart object value set in html via thymeleaf. **
        return "cart";
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CartViewModel {

    private String userId;
    //private List<ProductSelected> products;
    private List<ProductViewModel> products;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProductViewModel
{

    public String id;
    public int qty = 0;
    public String handle;
    public String title;
    public String bodyHTML;
    public String vendor;
    public String type;
    public String tags;
    public String variantPrice;
    public String imageSrc;
    public String imageAltText;

}
```

```html
<div class="container-main">
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:object="${vendorViewModel}" th:action="@{/inventory}">
    <div>
      <div style="float:left;padding-left:10px;">
        <label for="selectVendor" class="input-label-name">Select Vendor</label>
      </div>
      <div style="float:left;padding-left:10px;">

        <select id="selectVendor" required="required" th:field="*{id}" style="width:90%">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option th:each="vendor, iSat : ${vendors}" th:value="${vendor.id}" th:with="test=${vendor.name}" th:text="${vendor.name}">
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div style="float:left;padding-left:10px;">
        <input type="submit" value="Get Products" class="btn">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <form method="POST" action="#" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/cart}" th:object="${cart}">
    <!--                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49462788/how-to-post-a-list-to-controller-in-thymeleaf-->
    <div style="padding-top: 50px;">

      <table id="productTable" class="tableBodyScroll">
        <tr>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>QtyPrice</th>
          <th>Handle</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Tags</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <!--                            <th>IN STOCK</th>-->
        </tr>
        <tr th:id="${prod.id}" th:each="prod,iterStat : ${cart.products}" th:class="${iterStat.odd}? 'odd'">
          <td><span class="table-add"><button th:id="'add_' + ${prod.id}" type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">+</button></span>
            <span type="text" th:id="'count_' + ${prod.id}" th:field="*{products[__${iterStat.index}__].qty}">0</span>
            <span class="table-remove"><button  th:id="'remove_' + ${prod.id}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">-</button></span>
          </td>
          <td><span th:id="'qtyPrice_' + ${prod.id}">0</span></td>
          <td th:text="${prod.handle}"></td>
          <td th:text="${prod.title}"></td>
          <td th:text="${prod.type}"></td>
          <td th:text="${prod.tags}"></td>
          <td th:id="'price_' + ${prod.id}" th:text="${prod.variantPrice}"></td>
          <td><img height="50px" width="100px" th:src="${prod.imageSrc}" th:title="${prod.title}" th:alt="${prod.imageAltText}" /></td>
          <!--                            <td th:text="${prod.inStock}? #{true} : #{false}">yes</td>-->
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
    <div style="float:left;padding-left:10px;">
      <input type="submit" value="Go to Cart" class="btn">
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually did some work around to overcome my problem using ajax call. But later I came across [this](https://vkuzel.com/add-or-remove-items-from-a-list-of-objects-in-a-model-attribute-using-spring-mvc-and-thymeleaf), seems to be a better fit for my scenario.
Hope it would help someone.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.